# Starting multiple HomeBrew Services

Tags: macos, homebrew, services

I would like to run two different mongodb databases on my Mac. I installed mongodb with the HomeBrew manager. However I was unable to find a possibility to create new homebrew services. I already created the new config file and new location to store the data.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

First, you are not able to use `brew service` to start the two different `mongodb`. Cause the LaunchAgent `.plist` files have the same name. The former enable one will be overwritten by the latter one. Find the corresponding `.plist` service file, copy it to `~/Library/LaunchAgents` as a different name.

Secondly, the service `.plist` must be modified to use a different conf for `mongodb`. It's impossible to make two daemons listen on the same port.